# How to use regrex with AWK for string replacement in this example?

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression, awk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use regrex with AWK for string replacement in this example?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25122/how-to-use-regrex-with-awk-for-string-replacement-in-this-example)

Suppose there is some text from a file:

```
(bookmarks
("Chapter 1 Introduction 1" "#1"
("1.1 Problem Statement and Basic Definitions 23" "#2")
("Exercises 31" "#30")
("Notes and References 42" "#34"))
)
```

I want to add 11 to each number followed by a `"` in each line if there is one, ie

```
(bookmarks
("Chapter 1 Introduction 12" "#12"
("1.1 Problem Statement and Basic Definitions 34" "#13")
("Exercises 42" "#41")
("Notes and References 53" "#45"))
)
```

Here is my solution by using GNU AWK and regex:

```
awk -F'#' 'NF>1{gsub(/"(\d+)\""/, "\1+11\"")}'
```

i.e., I want to replace `(\d+)\"` with  `\1+10\"`, where `\1` is the group representing `(\d+)`. But it doesn't work. So I wonder how to make it work?

If gawk is not the best solution, what else can be used?

Thanks and regards!