# How to use regex with AWK for string replacement?

Tags: regular-expression, awk, text-processing

Suppose there is some text from a file:

```
(bookmarks
("Chapter 1 Introduction 1" "#1"
("1.1 Problem Statement and Basic Definitions 23" "#2")
("Exercises 31" "#30")
("Notes and References 42" "#34"))
)
```

I want to add 11 to each number followed by a `"` in each line if there is one, ie

```
(bookmarks
("Chapter 1 Introduction 12" "#12"
("1.1 Problem Statement and Basic Definitions 34" "#13")
("Exercises 42" "#41")
("Notes and References 53" "#45"))
)
```

Here is my solution by using GNU AWK and regex:

```
awk -F'#' 'NF>1{gsub(/"(\d+)\""/, "\1+11\"")}'
```

i.e., I want to replace `(\d+)\"` with  `\1+10\"`, where `\1` is the group representing `(\d+)`. But it doesn't work. How can I make it work?

If gawk is not the best solution, what else can be used?

Comment: Sorry about duplication. But I first asked on stackoverflow, and got no satisfactory answer, so I flagged for migration. But it didn't happen for a while, so I didn't expect it to happen and then asked on Unix.SE.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this (gawk is needed).

```
awk '{a=gensub(/.*#([0-9]+)(\").*/,"\\1","g",$0);if(a~/[0-9]+/) {gsub(/[0-9]+\"/,a+11"\"",$0);}print $0}' YourFile
```

**Test** with your example:

```
kent$  echo '(bookmarks
("Chapter 1 Introduction 1" "#1"
("1.1 Problem Statement and Basic Definitions 2" "#2")
("Exercises 30" "#30")
("Notes and References 34" "#34"))
)
'|awk '{a=gensub(/.*#([0-9]+)(\").*/,"\\1","g",$0);if(a~/[0-9]+/) {gsub(/[0-9]+\"/,a+11"\"",$0);}print $0}'   
(bookmarks
("Chapter 1 Introduction 12" "#12"
("1.1 Problem Statement and Basic Definitions 13" "#13")
("Exercises 41" "#41")
("Notes and References 45" "#45"))
)
```

Note that this command won't work if the two numbers (e.g. 1" and "#1") are different. or there are more numbers in same line with this pattern (e.g. 23" ...32"..."#123") in one line.

**UPDATE**

Since @Tim (OP) said the number followed by `"` in same line could be different, I did some changes on my previous solution, and made it work for your new example.

BTW, from the example I feel that it could be a table of content structure, so I don't see how the two numbers could be different. First would be the printed page number, and 2nd with # would be the page index. Am I right?

Anyway, you know your requirement best. Now the new solution, still with gawk (I break the command into lines to make it easier to read):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\" \"#"}{if(NF<2){print;next;}
        a=gensub(/.* ([0-9]+)$/,"\\1","g",$1);
        b=gensub(/([0-9]+)\"/,"\\1","g",$2); 
        gsub(/[0-9]+$/,a+11,$1);
        gsub(/^[0-9]+/,b+11,$2);
        print $1,$2
}' yourFile
```

**test** with your ***new*** example:

```
kent$  echo '(bookmarks
("Chapter 1 Introduction 1" "#1"
("1.1 Problem Statement and Basic Definitions 23" "#2")
("Exercises 31" "#30")
("Notes and References 42" "#34"))
)
'|awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\" \"#"}{if(NF<2){print;next;}
        a=gensub(/.* ([0-9]+)$/,"\\1","g",$1);
        b=gensub(/([0-9]+)\"/,"\\1","g",$2); 
        gsub(/[0-9]+$/,a+11,$1);
        gsub(/^[0-9]+/,b+11,$2);
        print $1,$2
}'                        
(bookmarks
("Chapter 1 Introduction 12" "#12"
("1.1 Problem Statement and Basic Definitions 34" "#13")
("Exercises 42" "#41")
("Notes and References 53" "#45"))
)
```

**EDIT2** based on @Tim 's comment

> (1) Does FS=OFS="\" \"#" mean the separator of field in both input and
>   output is double quote, space, double quote and #? Why specify double
>   quote twice?

You are right for the separator in both input and output part. It defined separator as:

```
" "#
```

There are two double quotes, because it is easier to catch the two numbers you want (based on your example input).

> (2) In /.* ([0-9]+)$/, does $ mean the end of the string?

Exactly!

> (3) In the third argument of gensub(), what is the difference between
>   "g" and "G"? there is no difference between G and g. Check this out:

```
gensub(regexp, replacement, how [, target]) #
    Search the target string target for matches of the regular expression regexp. 
    If "how" is a string beginning with ‘g’ or ‘G’ (short for “global”), then 
        replace all matches of regexp with replacement.
```

This is from http://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html. you can read to get detailed usage of gensub.

Comment: Thanks! I wonder how to make it work if the two numbers e.g. 1" and "#1" are different?

Comment: this answer works for your current reqirement/example. if the requirement is changed, maybe you could edit the question, and give a better example. and from your code `awk -F'#'`, it seems that you only want to do the change on the part  after the '#' ?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I just modified my example so that the two numbers are not the same.

Comment: @Tim see my updated answer, for your new example.

Comment: Thanks! Some questions: (1) does `FS=OFS="\" \"#"` mean the separator of field in both input and output is double quote, space, double quote and #? why specify double quote twice? (2)  in `/.* ([0-9]+)$/`, does `$` mean the end of the string? (3) in the third argument of gensub(), what is the difference between `"g"` and `"G"`?

Comment: check EDIT2 in my answer for the explanation.

Comment: How can I do this with a string that may have multiple, space separated "words" when I don't know how many words there are in any particular string?

Answer (score 8):

Unlike just about every tool that provides regexp substitutions, awk does not allow backreferences such as `\1` in replacement text. GNU Awk gives access to matched groups if you use the [`match` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#index-match_0028_0029-function), but not with `~` or `sub` or `gsub`.

Note also that even if `\1` was supported, your snippet would append the string `+11`, not perform a numerical computation. Also, your regexp isn't quite right, you're matching things like `"42""` and not `"#42"`.

Here's an awk solution (warning, untested). It only performs a single replacement per line.

```
awk '
  match($0, /"#[0-9]+"/) {
    n = substr($0, RSTART+2, RLENGTH-3) + 11;
    $0 = substr($0, 1, RSTART+1) n substr($0, RSTART+RLENGTH-1)
  }
  1 {print}'
```

It would be simpler in Perl.

```
perl -pe 's/(?<="#)[0-9]+(?=")/$1+11/e'
```

Comment: The first sentence of your answer is exactly what I was looking for.  However, the fact that you said "...in replacement text" raises a follow-up question: Does awk allow backreferences in the regex pattern itself?

Comment: @Wildcard No, awk just doesn't keep track of groups (except for the GNU extension I mention).

Answer (score 5):

`awk` can do it, but it isn't direct, even using backreferencing.
*GNU awk* has (partial) backreferecing, in the form of *[gensub](http://awk.freeshell.org/Backreferences)*.

Instances of `123"` are temporarily wrapped in  `\x01` and `\x02` to mark them as unmodified (for `sub()`.  co

Or you could just step through the loop changing candidates as you go, in which case, the backreferencing and "brackets" aren't needed; but keeping track of the character index is needed.

```
awk '{$0=gensub(/([0-9]+)\"/, "\x01\\1\"\x02", "g", $0 )
      while ( match($0, /\x01[0-9]+\"\x02/) ) {
        temp=substr( $0, RSTART, RLENGTH )
        numb=substr( temp, 2, RLENGTH-3 ) + 11
        sub( /\x01[0-9]+\"\x02/, numb "\"" ) 
      } print }'
```

---

Here is another way, using  `gensub` and array `split` and `\x01` as a field delimiter (for *split*).. \x02 marks an array element as a candidate for the arithmetic addition.

```
awk 'BEGIN{ ORS="" } {
     $0=gensub(/([0-9]+)\"/, "\x01\x02\\1\x01\"", "g", $0 )
     split( $0, a, "\x01" )
     for (i=0; i<length(a); i++) { 
       if( substr(a[i],1,1)=="\x02" ) { a[i]=substr(a[i],2) + 11 }
       print a[i]
     } print "\n" }'
```

Comment: Thanks! In your first code, (1) what does `"\x01\\1\"\x02"` mean? I still don't understand `\x01` and `\x02`. (2) how different is the return `$0` by `gensub` and the `$0` as the last argument to `gensub`?

Comment: *@Tim.* The hex values `\x01` and `\x02` are used as substitution markers. These values are **highly** unlikely to be in any **normal** text file, so they are equally "highly" safe to use (ie. not encounter a clash with pre-existing ones).. They are just temporary labels..   Re `$0=gensub(... $0)`.. see this link [String-Manipulation Functions](http://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html), but in summary: *It (gensub) returns the modified string as the result of the function and the original target string is not changed.*... The `$0=` simply modifies the original target..

Answer (score 3):

Since solutions in (g)awk seem to become quite complex, I wanted to add an alternative solution in Perl:

```
perl -wpe 's/\d+(?=")/$&+11/eg' < in.txt > out.txt
```

Explanation:

- Option `-w` enables warnings (which will warn you of possible unwanted effects).
- Option `-p` implies a loop around the code that works similar to sed or awk, saving each line of input automatically in the default variable, `$_`.
- Option `-e` tells perl that the program code is following on the command line, not in a script file.
- The code is a regex substitution (`s/.../.../`) on `$_`, where a sequence of digits, if it is followed by a `"`, will be replaced by the sequence, interpreted as a number in the addition, plus 11.
- The [zero-width positive look-ahead assertion](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns) `(?=pattern)` looks for the `"` without taking it into the match, so we do not have to repeat it in the replacement. The MATCH variable `$&` in the replacement will then contain only the number.
- The `/e` modifier to the regex tells `perl` to "execute" the replacement as code instead of taking it as a string.
- The `/g` modifier makes the replacement "global", repeating it on every match in the line.

The MATCH variable `$&` will unfortunately be detrimental to code performance in Perl versions before 5.20. A faster (and not much more complex) solution would use grouping and the backreference `$1` instead:

```
perl -wpe 's/(\d+)?="/$1+11/eg' < in.txt > out.txt
```

And if the look-ahead assertion looks too confusing, you could also replace the quotation mark explicitely:

```
perl -wpe 's/(\d+)"/$1+11 . q{"}/eg' < in.txt > out.txt
```